# REST client for NodeJS with Typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am developing a nodejs web application (express)
and would like to call my api.

I tryed a bunch including restangular and the jquery ajax calls.

What are good rest client libraries with Typescript definitions available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all honesty it depends on specific requirements.

[Request](https://github.com/request/request) is the gold standard as far as a library goes ( if you need the bells and whistles ). It's a mature and robust library with a thriving ecosystem and a well managed project.

Fetch is well on its' way to becoming the standard for making a rest call

Further reading - [Solid list of all things rest on github](https://github.com/marmelab/awesome-rest)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [fetch](http://github.github.io/fetch/) which is on track to becoming a standard. The link is to a polyfil for browsers that don't yet support `fetch`.

[Type Definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/whatwg-fetch/whatwg-fetch.d.ts) exist for it as well.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer , other answers are old.

Answer (score 3):

The [request](https://github.com/request/request#readme) library is capable of making simple `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` requests. TypeScript definitions are available via [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#readme).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Microsoft Typed Rest Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-rest-client) but I just realized it must have very sparse use: There is a bug for passing HTTP headers to the client constructor which hasn't been solved in several months. "NPM Weekly downloads" is high though for some reason...